# screen going to sleep while program still running in 11.10 32bit

Tags: 11.10, timeout

I have screen saver as well. But with 11.10 the screen goes black/blank while banshee is playing (full screen now playing mode) and while watching movies in VLC. I did not have this issue in any prior ubuntu releases. how can I stop my screen from blanking out while watching movies or running banshee in now playing full screen mode?

thank you for your time and answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you install caffeine - it is available via ppa from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/caffeine). 
Run the following in a terminal to install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

It is a status bar application able to temporarily prevent the activation of both the screensaver and the "sleep" powersaving mode.

Comment: is there any way to make rules for applications like vlc/totem and banshee about not putting the screen to sleep without adding anything else?

Comment: @Dustin - Not as far as I know, caffeine sits in the top menu bar and you simply click it once to disable the screensaver/power save mode and watch VLC/Totem/Banshee then click it again to re-enable. It's fairly simple and unobtrusive and one of the first things I install on my systems

Comment: Just wish there was another option because I have a netbook. thats skype, messaging, battery (plus time left) wireless, audio, time, name, takes up a lot of space.

Comment: @Dustin - you can remove your name from the menu bar using dconf editor, I've done it on my netbook for a much cleaner interface.